# get the last 5 unique created_at dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get the last 5 days that an object has. Currently my code is like this

```
Post.uniq('performed_at').ascending.last(5).group_by{|p| p.performed_at}
```

but I've been getting 4 dates instead of 5 and I think it's because there are 2 entries of the last 5 that are created on the same day. How do I accurately get the last 5 days where a Post has an entry?

Comment: Update. 

I got it working using some of @xdazz code.

    Post.select('performed_at').uniq.order('performed_at DESC').limit(5).pluck(:performed_at).reverse

I made a reverse since I want the last 5 days in chronological order. 

Also, I select('DISTINCT performed_at') returns a duplicate for me so instead I separated them by .select('performed_at').uniq

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
Post.select('DISTINCT created_at').order('created_at DESC').limit(5).pluck(:created_at)
```

Comment: I tried doing that, but instead of created_at I was doing a query with a different date 'performed_at' which is purely a date and not a timestamp. Technically it should have been the same but the results on console shows

2014-03-17
2014-03-12
2013-12-12
2013-12-12
2013-12-11

3rd and 4th Item seems to be still a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want the dates themselves, and not the unique datetimes, this would be better:

```
Post.order('created_at desc').uniq.limit(5).pluck('DATE(created_at)')
```

This will return just the unique calendar dates, without any specific times.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for this. I got it working and this is how I did it.

```
Post.select('performed_at').uniq.order('performed_at DESC').limit(5).pluck(:performed_at).reverse
```

I also added reverse since I want the array of days returned to me in chronological order. I also had it uniq() since select('DISTINCT performed_at') was still returning duplicate dates.

Hope this helps.